# Can I display column headings when querying via gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark-sql?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm issuing a spark-sql job to dataproc that simply displays some data from a table:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark-sql --cluster mycluster --region europe-west1 -e "select * from mydb.mytable limit 10"
```

When the data is returned and outputted to stdout I don't see column headings, I only see the raw data, whitespace delimited. I'd really like the output to be formatted better, specifically I'd like to see column headings. I tried this:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark-sql --cluster mycluster --region europe-west1 -e "SET hive.cli.print.header=true;select * from mydb.mytable limit 10"
```

But it had no affect.

Is there a way to get spark-sql to display column headings on dataproc?

If there is a way to get the data displayed like so:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Jim   |
| 2  | Ann   |
| 3  | Simon |
+----+-------+
```

then that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been performing some tests with a Dataproc cluster, and it looks like it is not possible to retrieve query results with the column names using Spark SQL. However, this is more a Apache Spark SQL issue, rather than Dataproc, so I have added that tag to your question too, in order for it to receive a better attention.

If you get into the Spark SQL console in your Dataproc cluster (by SSHing in the master and typing `spark-sql`), you will see that the result for *SELECT* queries does not include the table name:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
18/04/17 10:31:51 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 3
2       Ann
1       Jim
3       Simon
```

There's no change if using instead `SELECT ID FROM mytable;`. Therefore, the issue is not in the `gcloud dataproc jobs sbmit spark-sql` command, but instead in the fact that Spark SQL does not provide this type of data.

If you do not necessarily have to use Spark SQL, you can try [using HIVE](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/hive) instead. HIVE does provide the type of information you want (including the column names plus a prettier formatting):

```
user@project:~$ gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster <CLUSTER_NAME> -e "SELECT * FROM mytable;"
Job [JOB_ID] submitted.
Waiting for job output...
+-------------+---------------+--+
| mytable.id  | mytable.name  |
+-------------+---------------+--+
| 2           | Ann           |
| 1           | Jim           |
| 3           | Simon         |
+-------------+---------------+--+
Job [JOB_ID] finished successfully.
```

Comment: ah, good tip to try `gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive`. I've avoided that of late as in my experience `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark-sql` is (much) more reliable (many times I've seen hive fail with an identical query that works with spark-sql) but in this case hive may work well. thank you.

Comment: I am not aware of HIVE being more prone to errors than Spark SQL. I know that HIVE uses HiveQL, a simplified version of SQL, and that may be the reason for the failure of some specific queries. In any case, I am glad HIVE can satisfy your needs for this!